# Fatfs SPI Flash File System

Tags: spi, fatfs

I develop file system on spi flash memory with Chan's FATFS library.I create file on spi flash but not write anything.When i write some text on file i get disk full error.For fatfs library free space equal 0x0000 but on spi flash free space equal 0xFFFF so fatfs library think no free space on memory and return error.
I use SST26 series spi flash.
Can someone help me?How can i change this situation?How can i say to fatfs free space equal 0xFFFF and other value is not free for you ?

Best Regards

Comment: Post  your code (mark problem with comment) and link to library sources. It's too broad question.

Comment: I use Chan's FAT library  http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html I create file but not write anything in file.f_getfree function return no free space.Fatfs library 0xFFFF is full 0x0000 is empty.But this stiation wrong for nand flash.For nand flash 0xFFFF is free and the other value is full for nand flash.How can i change this situation for FATFS.How can i say to fatfs 0xFFFF is free for you?

Comment: It's seem as porting problem, I couldn't  help you without your code. `f_getfree` check headers, that must been initialized previously by functions `f_fdisk` and `f_mkfs`. 0xFFFF space is free for all flash memories and this fact is older then FAT library.

Comment: I think I couldn't have porting problem.Because my low level flash driver working good and I never change Fatfs library source.Which function check pointed address free or not ?

Comment: Could you tell us your SPI Flash page/sector and erase size? Moreover your ioctl code?